# h.playTouchSound is not a function?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I recently upgraded my React Native to 0.64. Everything works as expected but when building for production, the app crashes on launch. A quick logcat showed me the below error at the beginning of crash
h.playTouchSound is not a function.
I also read through [this](http://www.reactnative.com/react-native-v0-64-x-released/) article on the breaking changes with RN 0.64. It mentioned the following.

> Deletes the method PlayTouchSound method from UIManagerModule, this
> method was moved to the SoundManagerModule class. (d0c4c5eaf9 by
> @mdvacca)

Has anyone encountered this issue and What's the best way to resolve it?

Comment: i am also getting same bug on my android device.  Did you able to get a solution for this.

Comment: Did anyone resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the following code snippet into your index.js file and then rebuild your project:

```
// Disable the touch sound in the UIManager
UIManager.playTouchSound = () => {};
```

This code modification will help you suppress or disable the touch sound in your application.
I was able to fix the runtime crash after this change.